# Postgresql limit by N groups

Tags: postgresql

```
create table t (a integer, b text);
insert into t values (1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (10, 'b'), (11, 'b'), (0, 'c');
```

I need to limit select by 2 first groups of column **b** (1 - a, 2 - b);

```
select * from t order by b;
 a  | b 
----+---
  1 | a
  2 | a
  3 | a
 10 | b
 11 | b
 -- limit here
  0 | c
(6 rows)
```

Something like `where b in (select distinct(b) from t order by b limit 2)` whithout subquery.

Comment: Why "without subquery"?

Comment: Real case - b is not a table. It's a complex query with joins and filters. With subquery all filters applied to resultset twice. Like select top two auhtors and them books where book name like '%winter%'.

Comment: So, the column `a`- is it always incremental? How exactly do you know at what point to start counting for b?

Comment: Counting order by b. Values of `a` doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use windows functions like dense_rank :

```
select *,dense_rank()  over (order by  b) group_number from t order by b
```

so you can do :

```
select * from (
    select *,dense_rank() over (order by  b) group_number  from t order by b
) a where group_number<=2
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you.