# PostgreSQL - Show the last N rows for each sorted group

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

With respect to the following posts:

[Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

[Grouped LIMIT in PostgreSQL: show the first N rows for each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124603/grouped-limit-in-postgresql-show-the-first-n-rows-for-each-group)

[Postgresql limit by N groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278576/postgresql-limit-by-n-groups)

I wrote a query to find the latest 3 entries of the last 3 groups of log events partitioned by day with a maximum of 9 total entries and I managed to gather the following data from a postgresql log table:

[image]

The query I used to get them is the following:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY created_at::date ORDER BY created_at::time DESC) AS row_number,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY created_at::date DESC) AS group_number,
        l.*
    FROM
        logs l
    WHERE
        account_id = 1) subquery
WHERE
    subquery.row_number <= 3
    AND group_number <= 3
LIMIT 9;
```

However I'm missing one last step: The results are "grouped" by day in descending order (which is good) but **within each group** the ordering by time doesn't seem to work.

Effectively the expected order should be (displaying only each row's `id`):

```
| EXISTING ROW ORDERING | EXPECTED ROW ORDERING |
| --------------------- | --------------------- |         
           52                      56
           53                      53
           56                      52
           46                      48
           48                      47 
           47                      46
           30                      30
           31                      31
           32                      32
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the data in a particular order, then *you need to have an `order by`*.  SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  The only exception is when the outermost query has an `order by`.

So:

```
order by created_at desc
```

Comment: @kstratis . . . It is very easy to forget that result sets are not ordered, particularly when they look ordered due to underlying algorithms.